# Android lollipop Nexus5 mobile network exclamation mark

Tags: nexus-5, mobile-network, mobile-data

I am using nexus5 and I have never had problems using mobile data network. Some days ago I updated to 5.0.1 and problems started occuring, exclamation mark on mobile network icon, internet stopped working. Anyone hade same issues ? I probably flash back to Android 4

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it can help or not, but I also noticed this, and the indicator otherwise seemed to say I was having great cellular signal. The exclamation mark would mean that there is no data connection. So, I tried calling someone, and had no problem. Please note that I also have NO DATA PLAN with my provider and this is by choice. I also had data (LTE/3G/4G) disabled on the phone, as well as at the provider's web site. What I do not know is whether I will be able to know the strength of the cellular signal or not. I also would like if I will ever be able to get LTE/3G/4G data on this phone, should I choose to do so.

Comment: I can assure you my data were fine. The only difference was 5.0 and 5.0.1. Where in 5.0 internet connection was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding the Access Point details for your carrier, and changing the Access Point Settings in the Settings app. The exclamation mark is to represent a lack of internet connectivity, hence if you shut off your data plan, the exclamation mark comes up.